How do i use ANSI escape codes in Kotlin to display a word as a url in the terminal?
I would like to display a word in the terminal like 'Painting' and have it be clickable, transporting the user to a webpage.
In my code i have a variable containing a wikipedia link that i want the clickable word to go to
and a variable containing the word 'Painting'.
I have found a solution that uses ANSI escape code, however it seems kotlin does not recognize this, as this is my output :
Intellij terminal output
val link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painting"
val name = "Painting"


println("\u001B]8;;$link\u001B\\$name\u001B]8;;\u001B\\")

I was wondering if anyone knows of another solution, or if someone is able to point out to me where i might have made a typo in the code.

This question is similar to: How to add hyperlinks to a terminal. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. You need a terminal supporting it.
